# Very simple "insert a word to continue" script

Tags: jquery

I guess that this is a very easy question but I've not found any resources for that. Maybe it's the wrong terms I'm searching for.

I'm building a learning scenario for kids. Here they have to read a text and answer a question before they continue to the next text and question. What I don't get is the code where the kids have to write the text to get redirected.

Maybe there is a jQuery solution: a textfield with a button next to it ("go ahead") which is just clickable after a specific word is written into the textfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

making it as simple as i can....using `keyup()` and `prop()`.

try this

```
$(function(){  //<--make sure document is ready
  var $btn =  $('#buttonID'); 
  $btn.prop('disabled',true);   //<---disable the button on default
  $('#inputID').keyup(function(){ //<---check if something is typed in input 
    if($(this).val() != ""){
      $btn.prop('disabled',false);  
    }else{
      $btn.prop('disabled',true);
    }
  });
});
```

here `buttonID` and `inputID` is id of button and input respectively..

make sure your are loading the jquery,js script inside `<head>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: that is because you forgot to load jquery in the fiddle....here is working fiddle...check it out http://jsfiddle.net/JqxEY/1/

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like it should. The fault was, that WordPress don't like "$" for jQuery. So you first have to specify it: http://jsfiddle.net/JqxEY/2/

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to go with the solution you proposed, you could code like this:

```
var textbox = $("#idOfTextbox");
textbox.change(function () {
    $("idOfButton").prop("disabled", !textbox.val());
});
```

This should disable the button when the textbox is empty, and enable it again when there is text.

Comment: Thank you! I just need a specified text. So is it possible to set it here?

Comment: What do you mean, a specified text? If you mean only a certain word can cause the button to be enabled, just replace `!textbox.val()` with `textbox.val() == "word"` (where `word` is the relevant word that must be written).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function() {
    $('#input').on('keyup', function() {
      var $btn = $('#button')
      this.value === 'hello' ? $btn.prop('disabled', false) 
                            : $btn.prop('disabled', true) ;
    });
});
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/uxCZ2/1/)**

Comment: Wow! Fast answer.. ;) It works fine on Fiddle but as soon as I merge it into the website it's not working... ;(

`<script type="text/javascript">
$('#input').on('keyup', function() {
    var $btn = $('#button')
    this.value === 'hello' ? $btn.prop('disabled', false) :  $btn.prop('disabled', true) ;
});
</script>
<input type="text"  id="input"/>
<input type="button"  id="button" value="Go ahead" disabled="true"/>`

Comment: Check if enclosing the code in `DOM ready event` helps.. Also check if you see any errors in the console

Comment: Thank you! That was really useful. At the end it's doesn't matter which solution to use. Best!